# Adjust ListView Size inside InteractiveViewer widget, in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview

Im trying to adjust the height of my ListView in some way that when I zoom-in with the InteractiveViewer my ListView should changes its height, occupying only the visible part of the Interactive view:

[Widget with fixed size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCMUQ.png)

[Column grows with the zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXccV.png)

the ListView should grow until hits the visible size. The _adjustPosition make sure that the zoom contains always the top of the Columns,

```
void _adjustPosition(BuildContext context) {
    Matrix4 currentMatrix = _transformationController.value;

    currentMatrix.setTranslationRaw(currentMatrix.getTranslation().x, 0, 0);

    _transformationController.value = currentMatrix;
  }


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: InteractiveViewer(
        transformationController: _transformationController,
        onInteractionEnd: (details) {
          _adjustPosition(context);
        },
        panEnabled: true,
        panAxis: PanAxis.horizontal,
        constrained: true,
        child: FittedBox(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child:  Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [for (WeekDayCalenderModel day in weekModel.weekDays) Column(
             children: [
              _getColumnHeader(weekDay.date),
              ListView(
                children: children
              )
             ]
            )],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I`ve tired to put the ListView inside a StatefullWidget and update the height wighted by the scale of the zoom, but it turned out into a complete mess...